# "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get' " on django application

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I couldn't able to figure out where the error is from in my django application.

Internal Server Error: /app/register/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/stokesy/Desktop/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/stokesy/Desktop/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py", line 96, in **call**
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "/home/stokesy/Desktop/MyDjangoEnv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 26, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'`

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms import UserProfileInfoForm,UserForm

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
       return render(request,'basic_app/index.html')

def register(request):

       registered = False

       if request.method == "POST" :
              user_form = UserForm(data=request.POST)
              profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data=request.POST)


          if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                 user = user_form.save()
                 user.set_password(user.password)
                 user.save()

                 profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
                 profile.user = user

                 if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES :
                        profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

                 profile.save()

                 registered = True

          else :
                 print(user_form.errors,profile_form.errors)

   else:
          user_form = UserForm()
          profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

   return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html'),{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered}
```

Comment: You've messed up the render call. You need to move the closing parenthesis ")" to the end of the line

Comment: **`return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered})`**

Comment: oops that's a silly mistake ,Thanks :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did this wrong. You closed the render brackets before the dictionary.

```
return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html'),{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered}
```

You have do this

```
`return render(request,'basic_app/registration.html',{'user_form':user_form,'profile_form':profile_form,'registered':registered})`
```

Don't close **)** after dictionary because the dictionary is the third parameter.